# SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values 00913. 00000 - "too many values" for insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

```
CREATE TABLE AAA_MYTB_STUDENT
     (
          STUDENT_NIC INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          INSID INT NOT NULL,
          UNIID INT NOT NULL,
          FNAME VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
          MNAME VARCHAR(30),
          LNAME VARCHAR(30),
          ADDRL1 VARCHAR(15),
          ADDRL2 VARCHAR(15),
          ADDRL3 VARCHAR(15),
          ADDRL4 VARCHAR(15),
          BATCHNO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
          DOB DATE,
          GENDER CHAR(1)
    );
```

Above is my create table query which I have created in the oracle database using 19c edition.
Using below query I am trying to insert values to the created table.
But it keeps giving me below error message. Looked at many previous answers but I couldn't figure what's wrong with the query.

```
INSERT INTO AAA_MYTB_STUDENT(STUDENT_NIC, INSID, UNIID, FNAME, MNAME, LNAME, ADDRL1,ADDRL2, ADDRL3, ADDRL4, BATCHNO, DOB)
VALUES (873393262, 12345, 200569, "Chamara", "Munasinghe","Arachchige","123A", "DNR State", "HOMAGAMA","Sri Lanka","2021Jan001","1999/12/05","M");
```

SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GENDER` column is missing but once you fix that then you need to change the double quotation marks to single quotation marks.

- Double quotation marks signify an identifier that is case-sensitive (i.e. a column or table name).
- Single quotation marks signify a literal (i.e. a string).

```sql
INSERT INTO AAA_MYTB_STUDENT(
  STUDENT_NIC,
  INSID,
  UNIID,
  FNAME,
  MNAME,
  LNAME,
  ADDRL1,
  ADDRL2,
  ADDRL3,
  ADDRL4,
  BATCHNO,
  DOB,
  GENDER             -- The gender column was missing.
) VALUES (
  873393262,
  12345,
  200569,
  'Chamara',         -- Single quotes
  'Munasinghe',      -- Single quotes
  'Arachchige',      -- Single quotes
  '123A',            -- Single quotes
  'DNR State',       -- Single quotes
  'HOMAGAMA',        -- Single quotes
  'Sri Lanka',       -- Single quotes
  '2021Jan001',      -- Single quotes
  DATE '1999-12-05', -- Use a DATE literal
  'M'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The GENDER column is not in your insert statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO AAA_MYTB_STUDENT(STUDENT_NIC, INSID, UNIID, FNAME, MNAME, LNAME, ADDRL1,ADDRL2, ADDRL3, ADDRL4, BATCHNO, DOB, GENDER)
VALUES (873393262, 12345, 200569, "Chamara", "Munasinghe","Arachchige","123A", "DNR State", "HOMAGAMA","Sri Lanka","2021Jan001","1999/12/05","M");
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the number values supplied, is more than the number of columns mentioned in the insert clause.

In this case the "Gender" field is missing

```
INSERT INTO AAA_MYTB_STUDENT(STUDENT_NIC, INSID, UNIID, FNAME, MNAME, LNAME, ADDRL1,ADDRL2, ADDRL3, ADDRL4, BATCHNO, DOB)
VALUES (873393262, 12345, 200569, "Chamara", "Munasinghe","Arachchige","123A", "DNR State", "HOMAGAMA","Sri Lanka","2021Jan001","1999/12/05","M");
```